# How to save output of for loop operation in matlab

Tags: for-loop

I have a matrix A which has a size of 54x100. For some specific condition I perform an operation on each row of A. I need to save the output of this for loop. I've tried the following but it did not work.

```
S=zeros(54,100);
for i=1:54;
 Ri=A(i,:);
answer=mean(reshape(Ri,5,20),1);
S(i)=answer;
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab: For-loops only outputting zero into my vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614493/matlab-for-loops-only-outputting-zero-into-my-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, judging by your question I'd recommend some basic Matlab tutorials like [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts.html) or just detailed documentation like [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html).

To actually help you with your issue though; you can do this:

```
%% Make up A (since I don't know what it actually is)
n = 54; m = 100;
A = randn(n,m); % N x m matrix of random numbers

%% Loop over each row of A
S = cell(n,1);
for j = 1:n;
    Rj = A(j,:); % j'th row
    answer = mean(reshape(Rj,5,20),1); % some operation
    S{j} = answer; % store the answer in cell S
end
```

The problem was that your answer was not a single number (1x1 matrix) but a vector and so you got a dimension mismatch error. Above I'm putting the `answer`s into a cell object of size n. The result of your operation on j'th row can then be retrieved by calling `S{j}`.

Also:

- Do **not** using `i` as an iterator since it also represents the imaginary unit.
- Do not hard-code values but reference the existing ones. For example here I referenced `n` in the for-loop declaration as opposed to just writing `for j = 1:54` because otherwise, if I got struck by a fancy to use my code for a 53x100 array it would not work anymore.
- When you post your code I reccomend adding a minimal **working** example - a pece of code which people can just copy and paste into their Matlab (or whatever interpreter of whatever language) and run to reproduce your problem. Here you have not included anything which tells the code what `A` is, for example.
- [This](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1001745#s2) is quite a good read in general and should help you in the future